# Integrate Optaplanner into Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, io, persistence, optaplanner

Trying to create a Java Web Application for Employee (Nurse) Rostering using Optaplanner. What is the best approach for this? I know about OptaWeb application but I really need to do this from scratch for my thesis. Should I use a persistent approach or is there a more simplistic way like org.optaplanner.training.workerrostering.app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, everyone figures this out on their own. But soon, we 'll have clean, simple, and still very powerful examples for

- Quarkus (almost finished)
- Spring Boot (finished) [Guide here](https://github.com/spring-guides/getting-started-guides/pull/126)

Comment: We are trying to use Optaplanner in Quarkus. It runs very well but hitting a bit of a wall when trying to compile to native code. Is this even feasible at this point?

Comment: We're working on it :) https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/5622 Hang tight!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a million.

Comment: Is there a way to access the solver API through REST service? Is there a guide for this? It's getting hard for me to understand how to model my input and intergrate the solver in my application. I just need to pass the data to the solver and get the solution/response somehow... I am really sorry I can't follow :(. Thanks

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΒογιατζάκης Yes there is, see https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner